# How to add tags (custom taxonomy) to post class css?

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, loop, css, tags

I am trying to figure out how to add my custom taxonomy for tags to the post class css when I already have added the custom taxonomy for categories. The code Im currently using to add the category taxonomy is -

```
  <?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'videoscategory' ); ?>
  <div class="box<?php foreach( $terms as $term ) echo ' ' . $term->slug; ?>">
```

This works fine but I also need to add a class for tags I've created with a custom taxonomy. I came across this code that will add the regular tags, but I need to use my custom tags.

```
<?php $tags = get_the_tags();
if( $tags ) : ?>
  <?php foreach( $tags as $tag ) { ?>
   <span class="<?php echo $tag->slug; ?>"><a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a></span>
  <?php } ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does any one have an idea?

Comment: I think I found a possible solution but the problem is Im getting all the tags instead of just one that is attached to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out how to add the terms to div's class -

In the code I have first the category, then the post type, then a custom taxonomy tag term assigned to it -

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'YOUR CUSTOM TAXONOMY CAT' ); ?>
 <?php $post_type = get_post_type($post->ID); ?>
<div class="box<?php foreach( $terms as $term ) echo ' ' . $term->slug; ?><?php echo ' '.get_post_type( $post->ID ); ?> <?php  $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'YOUR CUSTOM TAXONOMY TAGS');  
foreach ($terms as $term) {  
    echo $term->slug;  
}  
 ?>">
```